# C# - Multithreaded Processing of a single Image (Webcam Frames)

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, image-processing, unsafe

I have made a programm which is able to capture webcam frames and display them after running different per pixel algorithms - for example making the image gray scale.
At the moment I am using the FastBitmap class (can't find the link atm) which uses pointers to set and get a pixel within a bitmap.

However, I wanted to make my programm multithreaded so that multiple threads are working on the same image. For that I split the image into several sections via its BitmapData (one section per thread) and let the different threads work on their given section BitmapData. In the end a "manager" waits until all threads are done (join) and hands in the resulting image.
That's the theory, but in real this isn't working for me.

When I run this programm I get some strange errors, telling me that I have to release the LHC before reusing it, that I am accessing illegal memory, external exceptions etc. ... Everytime another and I can't understand why but I think the BitmapData sections are the main problem but I don't want to use the slower Mashal copy!

So my questions are the following:

- Is it possible to have sectioned multithreaded image processing in C# with unsafe pointer methods?
- If yes - how?

As for image processing libraries:
I don't need filters or some default image processing algorithms but I need my own "per pixel" algorithm - I even thought about adding a pixel shader to my program. xD

As my programm is based around the converting of frames of a webcam I need the fastest algorithm possible.
I've read all forum posts and tutorials etc. which I could just find and still have no idea how to do this with unsafe code correctly until I've made this account to finally ask this question here.

Robbepop

Comment: How are you splitting the `BitmapData` into "sections"? As far as problems with accessing memory, it's because you have a bug in your program. There is nothing magic about the way the `BitmapData` is stored or accessed. Without seeing code, we can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow an Image to be accessed by several threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497537/allow-an-image-to-be-accessed-by-several-threads)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible :)

Take a look at:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

This library contains exactly want you want:
parallel processor which is used to execute parallel operations on an image (e.g. color conversion) and yes those functions which operate on an image are unsafe (use pointers):

NuGet packages ready.