# Allow an Image to be accessed by several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

I'm trying to do some image processing in C#.
I want to use some threads to do parallel computations on several zones in my image.
Threads are actually getting and setting pixels in a Bitmap object. There is absolutely no chance for 2 threads to access the same pixel, so that's not the problem.

The problem is that C# doesnt allow me to start several threads on the same Bitmap object, even if i'm sure that the same pixel won't be read and modified simultaneously.

Is there any way to avoid C# to raise this error ? Or is it just impossible to run several threads on my Bitmap object ?

Thank you,

Pierre-Olivier

Comment: Your terminology is confusing, how do you "run a thread on an object"? What exactly is stopping your threads from accessing a shared variable? Please post the code you say isn't working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Threaded image processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650784/c-sharp-threaded-image-processing)

Comment: This topic recommand to make the access to the bitmap object thread safe. I actually want to break this "security", because, as I told it in the question, it's totally impossible that the same pixel is accessed and modified by different threads.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with C# or pixels, the Image class prevents two threads from accessing a *bitmap* at the same time.  It is a fundamental restriction, essential to avoid code dying a micro-locking perf death, you will have to work around it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using [`LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (*which is also much faster than `GetPixel` & `SetPixel`*) you can copy the image's pixels to a buffer, run parallel threads on it, and then copy the buffer back.

Here is a working example.

```
void Test()
{
    string inputFile = @"e:\temp\a.jpg";
    string outputFile = @"e:\temp\b.jpg";

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(inputFile) as Bitmap;

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    var data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
    var depth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(data.PixelFormat) / 8; //bytes per pixel

    var buffer = new byte[data.Width * data.Height * depth];

    //copy pixels to buffer
    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => {
            //upper-left
            Process(buffer, 0, 0, data.Width / 2, data.Height / 2, data.Width, depth);
        },
        () => {
            //lower-right
            Process(buffer, data.Width / 2, data.Height / 2, data.Width, data.Height, data.Width, depth);
        }
    );

    //Copy the buffer back to image
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, data.Scan0, buffer.Length);

    bmp.UnlockBits(data);

    bmp.Save(outputFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

void Process(byte[] buffer, int x, int y, int endx, int endy, int width, int depth)
{
    for (int i = x; i < endx; i++)
    {
        for (int j = y; j < endy; j++)
        {
            var offset = ((j * width) + i) * depth;
            // Dummy work    
            // To grayscale (0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B)
            var b = 0.2126 * buffer[offset + 0] + 0.7152 * buffer[offset + 1] + 0.0722 * buffer[offset + 2];
            buffer[offset + 0] = buffer[offset + 1] = buffer[offset + 2] = (byte)b;
        }
    }
}
```

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Output Image:**

[image]

**Some rough tests:**

Converting a (*41 MegaPixel, [7152x5368]*) image to a gray scale on a *dual core 2.1GHz machine*

- GetPixel/SetPixel - Single Core - 131 sec.
- LockBits  - Single Core - 4.5 sec.
- LockBits  - Dual Core - 3 sec.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That's exactly what i finally did. I just saw your message so i already found a solution by myself but didnt have the time to post earlyer. Thank you again !

Comment: I've just found this answer. It perfectly works within my MPI.Net application.

Comment: how to do the same in android?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to create a temporary container with the information about the `Bitmap` such as width, height, stride, buffer and pixel format. Once you need to access the `Bitmap` in parallel just create it based on the information in the temporary container.

For this we need an extension method to get the buffer and stride of a `Bitmap`:

```
public static Tuple<IntPtr, int> ToBufferAndStride(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapData bitmapData = null;

    try
    {
        bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), 
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        return new Tuple<IntPtr, int>(bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bitmapData != null)
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

This extension method will be used inside the temporary container:

```
public class BitmapContainer
{
    public PixelFormat Format { get; }

    public int Width { get; }

    public int Height { get; }

    public IntPtr Buffer { get; }

    public int Stride { get; set; }

    public BitmapContainer(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bitmap));

        Format = bitmap.PixelFormat;
        Width = bitmap.Width;
        Height = bitmap.Height;

        var bufferAndStride = bitmap.ToBufferAndStride();
        Buffer = bufferAndStride.Item1;
        Stride = bufferAndStride.Item2;
    }

    public Bitmap ToBitmap()
    {
        return new Bitmap(Width, Height, Stride, Format, Buffer);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `BitmapContainer` in a method executed in parallel:

```
BitmapContainer container = new BitmapContainer(bitmap);

Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    Bitmap parallelBitmap = container.ToBitmap();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Is this safe? I see no issues with it yet, and it works great. But... WHY is this not the solution for everyone all the time then?